# Somehow my value never equals 1, is there a reason for that?

Tags: c#

I can't ever get guessLimit to equal 1, in the system log when I enter the limit of guesses as 5 and start guessing, the guessLimit will go down all the way to 2 and it will give me the "You Lose" message without letting me do my final guess...
 is there a reason for that?

```
public static void Main(string[] args){
    string guess = "";
    bool outOfguesses = false;
    int guessCount = 0;
    Console.Clear();
    Console.Write("Enter the amount of guesses you want: ");
    int guessLimit = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Clear();
    Console.Write("Enter a word that will be guessed...: ");
    string secretWord = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Clear();
    Console.Write("You have " + guessLimit + " guesses" + "\nEnter a guess: ");
    guess = Console.ReadLine();
    while(guess.ToLower() != secretWord.ToLower() && !outOfguesses){
      if(guessLimit >= guessCount || guessLimit == 1){
        guessCount++;
        guessLimit--;
        Console.Write("\nWRONG! You have " + guessLimit + " guesses left." + "\nEnter another guess: ");
        guess = Console.ReadLine();
      } else{
        outOfguesses = true;
      }
    }
    if(outOfguesses == true){
      Console.WriteLine("\nSorry...\nYou lose!");
    } else{
      Console.WriteLine("\nGood Job.\nYou Win!!");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
  }
```

Comment: Have you used the breakpoints and debugger to see whats going on with your program? Hint.. look at your if statement and see why guessLimit is 1 (when you think its 2).

Comment: I don't know what does are, I just started learning C# yesterday so I'm new 

Comment: Great time to learn!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/debugging-with-visual-studio?tabs=csharp and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2019

Comment: [First look at the Visual Studio Debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019) and [Introduction to debugging](https://csharp.net-tutorials.com/debugging/introduction/). What you want to do is set a break point for the debugger to pause execution on, and then step through line by line inspecting each variable to see how they change, and where behaviour diverges from your expectations.

Comment: you're incrementing `GuessCount` and decrementing `GuessLimit` at the same time, thus one of them will reach the other before `GuessLimit` reaches 1 (unless `GuessLimit` <2)

Answer (score 0):

When your if statement reaches
(Is 2 >= 3) this is false so it will skip over the if and go to the else
Which is why it stops there.
Also change your guesslimit ==1 to <1